# How to maintain spinner selected state in android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I just wanna maintain spinner selected state in android.I've an activity A which retrieves data from webservice & popped into spinner.After select any one item from that and goes to another activity B.Once back to activity A.,i need to show selected item on spinner without go to web call again.

My Code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
if(spinnerFlag=1){
        spinner.setSelection(index);
    }
    else{
        //Web call for spinner data
    }
...    
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int arg2, long arg3) {

                    String seletcedProductName = parent.getSelectedItem()
                            .toString();
                    spinnerFlag=0;
                    index=arg2;


                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }
            });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the index in SharedPreferences on activity stop, retrieve it when you return to that activity.

[Shared Preferences at Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can save selected index of spinner in static variable, initialized with -1, and onResume check the value of that variable, if it's not -1, then set the selected index of spinner with it.

```
static int position=-1;



spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int arg2, long arg3) {

                    String seletcedProductName = parent.getSelectedItem()
                            .toString();
                    spinnerFlag=0;
                    index=arg2;
            position=arg2;  


                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }
            });


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(position!=-){
        spinner.setSelection(index);

        }

}
```

Comment: this is unreliable due to the way android handles garbage collection, you're better off using a shared preference or passing a bundle around